# Origin of MongoDB Opened Connections

Tags: mongodb

I have a expressjs applications deployed on EC2 VMs and use a Mongo DB in separate VM, and I am trying to find which VMs currently have open connections to the Mongo DB.

Is there away (or interface) to list the IP addresses of the currently opened MongoDB Connections ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5085 the one method is:

```
db.currentOp(true)
```